# dynamic form validation jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-plugins

validation works fine with the form and validation plugin as static form. i need to insert the form into the page and then have it validate - not working for me.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var validator = $("#loginForm").validate({
       // rules for field names
       rules: {
            cname: "required", 
            cpass: "required"
    },
    // inline error messages for fields above
    messages: {

            cname: "required", 
            cpass: "required"
    }
}); // for validating the form

$("#loginForm").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) { //Only runs when valid
      form.submit();
  }
});   

  var htmlStr = '<form class="cmxform" id="loginForm" method="get" action="https://www.myURL.com/login.php"><p><label for="cname">Name</label><em>*</em><input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" /></p><p><label for="cpass">Password</label><em>*</em><input type="password" id="cpass" name="pass" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" /></p><input id="mySubmit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/></form>';

  function createForm(){
  // fires with body onload
  $("#login-container").html(htmlStr);
     };
```

Comment: Is there any content in #login-container before adding htmlStr?

Comment: no. the form appears properly, it just doesnt go thru validation before submitting. it just submits.

Comment: Try removing function createForm() and just have $("#login-container").html(htmlStr);. Does not look like anything is triggering the function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your validation code to right after you add the html to the page.  Since `$("#loginForm")` likely doesn't exist in your `document.ready` function, nothing in the `validate` area ever gets run.  You probably want your code to look like this:

```
function createForm(){
  // fires with body onload
  $("#login-container").html(htmlStr);

  var validator = $("#loginForm").validate({
     // rules for field names
     rules: {
            cname: "required", 
            cpass: "required"
    },
    // inline error messages for fields above
    messages: {
            cname: "required", 
            cpass: "required"
    }
  });  
}
```

Other problems you had - no need to submit the form manually in `submitHandler` - the validator will do that for you if the form is valid.  Also, with the way you've set up your messages object, the actual error message will be the word "required".  Not sure if that's what you want or not...

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `delegate` function  of jquery to make it works with dynamic elements :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlStr = '<form class="cmxform" id="loginForm" method="post" action="https://www.myURL.com/login.php"><p><label for="cname">Name</label><em>*</em><input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="5" /></p><p><label for="cpass">Password</label><em>*</em><input type="password" id="cpass" name="pass" size="25" class="required" minlength="8" /></p><input id="mySubmit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/></form>';


function createForm(){
     $("#login-container").html(htmlStr);
     var validator = $("#loginForm").validate({
       });  
 };

 <body onload="createForm()">

<div id="login-container">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What im finding is that adding rules this way isnt working for me, perhaps because the rules are outlined in the HTML that is inserted, versus adding the rules later with var validator = (the rules). The only way these inline rules will work, when they are part of the inserted HTML is for me to add a function, just as if adding rules, but none are added. Code below. The form is generated dynamically, inserted dynamically and the rules have to be just as dynamic. Is this approach I'm taking correct, or does this just happen to work?

```
  var htmlStr = '<form class="cmxform" id="loginForm" method="post" action="https://www.myURL.com/login.php"><p><label for="cname">Name</label><em>*</em><input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="5" /></p><p><label for="cpass">Password</label><em>*</em><input type="password" id="cpass" name="pass" size="25" class="required" minlength="8" /></p><input id="mySubmit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/></form>';

  function createForm(){
   $("#login-container").html(htmlStr);
   var validator = $("#loginForm").validate({
     });  
  };
```

Comment: An example of the rule being included as part of the inserted HTML is  <input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="5"> where the size is called out, as is class required and minlength.